# Pythagorean Eqn. with Proportions

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What are the side lengths of a 14" HD screen? This is not trivial to me because the side lengths must remain a 16x9 proportion. 
Seems like the solution could come from:

```
16a^2+9b^2=196
```

I can use this to get the number but I want to see how it's worked out.
http://screen-size.info/

Like how do the exponents interact with the coefficients? I asked two tutors and they both were stumped....

Answer (score 1):

Let the longer side be $a$.  If the sides have ratio $16:9$, the shorter side has length $\frac{9}{16}a$.  Now
$$
    a^2 + \left(\frac{9}{16}a\right)^2 = 196
$$
and solve for $a$.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, if your sides are $a$ and $b$, then you get the right triangle 
$$a^2+b^2=14^2=196.$$
THen you apply the condition on the side ratio:
$$\frac {a}{b} = \frac {9}{16},$$
which gives you the equation
$$\left(\frac {9}{16}b\right)^2 +  b^2 = 196, $$which is easy to solve.

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if wrong:

Given the proportion: $16:9$.

Any rectangle with sides $16x$ and $9x$, $x$ real and positive,  will do.

Pythagoras:

$d^2 = (16x)^2 + (9x)^2 =(16^2+9^2)x^2$.

For a given $d$ find $x,$ and the side lengths $16x$ and $9x$.